# TypeScript "map" function in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, typescript

I have code in TypeScript and I need equivalent code in C#.

Declaration:

```
private sessionCommands: SessionCommand[];
// . . .
// Create array in constructor.
this.sessionCommands = new Array();
// . . .
// Push few objects to array in some method
```

And then get data. This is important part, how to do this in C# ?

```
var data = this.sessionCommands.map(x => x.identifier + " " + x.getParameter() + ";").join("\n");
```

Comment: It's Select method of LINQ.

Comment: Rather than showing the TypeScript code, it would be more useful to describe what you're trying to achieve. That way, you're not relying on readers who know both TypeScript *and* C#. My guess is that you're just looking for the `Select` method from LINQ...

Comment: I am doing migration from type script. I am not 100% sure what am I doing yet :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent in the .NET world is the Select function:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

It works on all kinds of enumerable types (including arrays). However it's an extension method, and you have to import `System.Linq` to be able to use it.

Full example for your code:

```
var data = String.Join("\n", this.sessionCommands.Select(x => x.identifier + " " + x.getParameter() + ";"));
```